# How to become a Game Programmer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I'm a 2nd-year student doing my bachelor's degree in Computer Applications. I'm really interested in becoming a Game Programmer and my dream is to work at Rockstar Games(it sounds a bit crazy). I'm really worried and I don't know how to program or write code. I'm an absolute beginner. Do you have any tips or advice on how to get there and fulfill my dream? Thanks.

Comment: Look into Meetup.com and look for local Gaming / Unity gaming groups.  You can get together with them and participate and learn.  I did years ago, but that was short-lived due to other obligations taking priority.  However, it was fun and the people were all cool/casual, some intense and real-bright with their specialties... sound, animation, graphics, game design/features.

Comment: Also make sure to read a bit about game developers experiences in the industry. It's sadly not all sunshine and it's logical: Every other young gamers wish is to be a games dev. As a result there are MANY out there pursuing this and thus the studios can afford to pay less and put their people through crunch times. I used to dream of this too but am nowadays happy to be a dev in an entirely different programming field and do games stuff as a hobby.
Of course maybe you have more passion than I had, but make sure you gather information :)

Comment: I would try to get a bit of a handle on C++ first (no need to get to expert level- just be sure you can write a few small programs). Then just start making games, id pursue only one engine as for things not to get overwhelming. Using art and sound packs is absolutely fine so long as things a properly credited. During this time attending game jams, even virtually would be a good idea. Main thing large employers look for in the UK is strong programming skills, a keen eye for design and being up for teamwork/cross department communication (also a bit of vector/matrix maths).

Comment: Also, the Our Machinery & Casey Muratori blogs have some great stuff on game programming (although a lot of the our machinery posts lean towards engine programming). There's also a web series called hand made hero, which might is a walkthrough of Casey making a game from scratch. Most of it won't get you hired into a large team - but if you're not sure between engine code and game code. Or just want to know how games work at a deeper level, then it'll be interesting. Oh and check out the gdc vault - there's plenty of free stuff there about design, game and engine code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work as a gameplay programmer in Canada so here's a few thing I can tell you.

Best place to start is doing the tutorials on the Unity website. Make a few that interests you and see how you like that. Unity is used in a lot of studios and it's very easy to find a ton of resources online for it. Once your more comfortable with it i'd experiment with unreal also to get an idea for more than 1 engine. While doing all that the idea is for you to build a portfolio of games/projects you can show an employer. Its ez to make ios/android builds to have portable visuals. Game jams are a great place to hone in some skills. Most game jam even lets you join in alone so teams missing people can add you in(programmers are usualy whats missing the most).

For the game industry more or less any programming degree can do but every studio will make you pass a programming test. Knowledge of the engine they use be it Unity/Unreal will be very important. For bigger studios that use their own they look for good c++/c# knowledge an often more experience. At the momment the industry is in dire need of people so its def a good time to join.

If rockstar is your ultimate goal you can certainly try and apply there right away (there's no harm), but its often more difficult to get in via larger studios when you don't know anyone there (also knowing someone on the inside is a major plus anywhere). But even if you don't know anyone, smaller studios have a lot of opennings at the momment and will often give you a a chance. 3 to 5 years experience in is when most opportunities might open up. But again depending on the labour market place may be more desperate.